# Autodesk Forge European server for design Automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

The base url for posting a Design Automation workitem is
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/v3/workitems
which points to a US east coast location for the server.

Several other Forge API's have a way to specify that they should be handled by European servers (both by adding the region to the URL and by options specifying which region the request should be handled in)

This possibility seems to be missing for the Design Automation API.

Is this correct and is this API currently limited to only a single USA server?
If not, is there documentation available where I can find how to direct a workitem to a European server?

I am asking because we are running Inventor design automation jobs from a website and these typically take 45 to 55 seconds to complete from start to displaying the modified design. However, occasionally a task takes 2 to 4 minutes and I am trying to find if this could be caused by a congested server queue. If there is more than one server I can try to run the same job on different servers and at different times of day to see if there is a commonality between these occasional delays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Design Automation is only available in **us-east** region.

> However, occasionally a task takes 2 to 4 minutes and I am trying to find if this could be caused by a congested server queue.

The [[GET] workitems/:id](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/workitems-id-GET/) endpoint returns various statistics. You can derive the information about how long your workitem spent in the queue by subtracting `timeQueued` from `timeDownloadStarted`.

```json
    "stats": {
        "timeQueued": "2022-03-28T12:34:18.3289895Z",
        "timeDownloadStarted": "2022-03-28T12:34:18.5377785Z",
        "timeInstructionsStarted": "2022-03-28T12:34:19.6206329Z",
        "timeInstructionsEnded": "2022-03-28T12:34:36.1960527Z",
        "timeFinished": "2022-03-28T12:34:36.2611905Z",
        "bytesDownloaded": 106
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

While I see some benefits in hitting the server which is closer to your geographical location (which is not possible for Design Automation at this point) those benefits would not include much of an improvement in the workitem processing time. You are today indeed reaching to "one" server in the US, but your workitems are being processed by several computers in the background.